# How to pull data from adjacent cells only if another value is true?

Tags: python, csv

In Python, I have a CSV file with data in Column A. I am trying to pull only data from its adjacent cell in Column B if a certain value in Column A is true.

What would the code be for that?

For example:

I just want to pull adjacent data from Column B if Column A is TN.

```
A     B

NY    123

NY    456

TN    789

TN    100
```

Comment: When you say "pull" data, what do you expect the code to do? If that is your example input CSV, what is the expected output or the expected result of running the code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's CSV library to help you. For example:

```py
import csv

data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input) # skip over the header
    
    for col_a, col_b in csv_input:
        if col_a == 'NY':
            data.append(col_b)
            
print(data)
```

So if `input.csv` contains:

```
A,B
NY,123
NY,456
TN,789
TN,100
```

Then the script would display:

```
['123', '456']
```

You could convert them to numbers if needed by using this instead:

```py
data.append(int(col_b))
```